# How to reduce the height of three views in carousel container in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

I have implemented a carousel using following link: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/community/carouselcontainer/viewer.html

I have added 4 views in the carousel container. I want vertical scroll for one view and not for the remaining views. I am getting all views vertically scrollable now. Can anybody tell me how to avoid vertical scroll for the remaining views? I have added my view in my code.

Thanks

Comment: the link is **not found**

Comment: @A.S.Roma now link is working

Comment: First of all I see 3 views. Second, only one has vertical scroll bar. I do not see for the other two

Comment: @A.S Roma.I have added my 4 view in my code

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.I set height for parent container